# python: can i set a variable to equal a function of itself?

Tags: python

Can I do this?

```
var1 = some_function(var1)
```

When I tried to do this I got errors, but perhaps I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Why not?  Please post **actual** code with **actual** error messages.

Comment: @S.Lott that completely misses the point of this question. "actual" code with "actual" error messages wouldn't even make this question better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the variable has been previously defined, you can do that yes.

Example:

```
def f(x):
    return x+1

var1 = 5
var1 = f(var1)
# var1 is now 6
```

If the variable has not been defined previously, you can't do that, simply because there is no value that could be passed to the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
def myfun(param):
    return param * 2

y = 4
y = myfun(y)
print (y)
```

Works fine. prints `8`;

So you could describe better the problem you're experiencing, preferably with full error traceback and source code I can run to reproduce the problem.